# Pass data to kendo ui

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

```
@{
reModel rm = new reModel();
IList<ReRoomType> types = rm.ReRoomTypes.ToList();
foreach( ReRoomType type in types)
{

<li><a href="#" onclick="showDetail(@type.PKiRoomTypeID)">@type.SRoomTypeName</a></li>
}
}
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("window")
.Title("Detail Information")
.Content("")
.Draggable()
.Resizable()
.Width(600)
.Actions(actions => actions.Refresh().Maximize().Close())
)
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDetail(id)
{
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#window").data("kendoWindow").center();
    $("#window").data("kendoWindow").open();

});
}
</script>
```

there's the whole stuff i did, now how can i pass something like ID or name or etc ....
from the List to the window

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any window @ your code?

Basically you can configure the Window to be initially invisible like this:

```
@Html.Kendo().Window().Name("foo").Visible(false)
```

Comment: thanks to answer my question
the first problem is solved
but how can i pass data from list to kendo window

Comment: Do not forget to mark as answered if that's what you were trying to achieve :P